# Nmap reporting incorrect results from an idle scan

Tags: linux, tcp, tcpip, nmap, port-scanning

I have a VPS that I was scanning to make sure everything is in check. A regular SYN scan reports that ports 25 and 80 are open (which they should be). When I run an [idle scan](http://nmap.org/book/idlescan.html) however, I get back that all 1000 ports scanned are closed|filtered. I have tried the SYN scan and the idle scan on a few other servers and also have tried different zombies when doing an idle scan.

On another server I was testing this against, it had about 9 ports open but, again, the idle scan showed that all 1000 ports were closed|filtered.

Any ideas on why this is happening? I've read over the documentation about the idle scan and understand that it cannot determine the difference between a closed and filtered port due to the way it works, but since these servers have ports open I don't understand why the idle scan is picking them up as either closed or filtered.

Comment: Why are you trying to run an idle scan? (Note: it's not actually idle, just obfuscated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nmap Idle Scan is a very fragile creature.  From the [Idle Scan information](http://nmap.org/book/idlescan.html):

> The first step in executing an IP ID idle scan is to find an
>   appropriate zombie. It needs to assign IP ID packets incrementally on
>   a global (rather than per-host it communicates with) basis. It should
>   be idle (hence the scan name), as extraneous traffic will bump up its
>   IP ID sequence, confusing the scan logic. The lower the latency
>   between the attacker and the zombie, and between the zombie and the
>   target, the faster the scan will proceed.

It sounds like your zombie is not suitable: Either it's not idle enough, it uses a "random positive increment" strategy for IP IDs (which also confuses the scan logic),  or it assigns IP IDs based on the host it's talking to rather than using a global counter (so your IP ID is independent of other traffic, which breaks the scan logic entirely).

Comment: To add to this, review the second on the linked page titled "Finding a Working Idle Scan Zombie Host" - most modern IP stacks won't behave the way nmap is expecting them to in an idle scan.